# Sorting data based on portion of the word

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, string, algorithm

I have an array of string that I would like to have sorted based on the portion of the word. For instance, if I gave "comp" as the search word, it would sort the array in a descending order which starts with "comp", such as "compare", "composition", "computer" etc. Rest of the words that do not match is either left alone or sorted in an alphabetical order (whichever is easier).

Having that said, what is the algorithm that I can use to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will select words you need and sort only those words:

```
var sortedWords = words.Where(x => x.Contains("comp"))
                       .OrderByDescending(x => x);
```

Comment: Wow, I have neglected LINQ for a long time because I don't like functional languages but I can see how it could be so useful.

I actually have the mentioned strings on a datagridview. What would be the easiest way to accomplish the above feature to sort the strings that is in a column?